# Confused about pushing Docker image to Dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, dockerhub

Docker newbie here: I have my local development environment set up with Docker desktop on OSX. When I want to push my Docker image to Dockerhub and I am updating the Dockerfile do I need to relaunch my container or is that not necessary? When I update the Dockerfile, tag it with the "latest" tag and push it to Dockerhub and then try to pull it into Kubernetes through Drone it seems to constantly be the old Docker image. At least Drone or Kubernetes are not loading the newest version. Can I access the actual Dockerfile on Dockerhub to double check if it has been pushed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When tagging images, the best practice is setting a separate tag for each new version (using semantic versioning, commit hash or any other system that suites you) rather than using the `latest`.
Using the `latest` tag can create unforeseen consequences as pods are rescheduled across your cluster and can lead to disparate versions running concurrently.

If you do insist on using the `latest` version, you can set the `imagePullPolicy` of your deployment to `Always`, which will prompt k8s to try and pull the current version of the image, even if it's already present on the machine. See more details in the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy).

Comment: Thank you. What about the image? Can I just change the Dockerfile and push that to Dockerhub or do I need to run docker-compose build? And as a follow up, won't I loose everything that I loaded in the container if I run docker-compose build again?

Comment: When you make a change to the Dockerfile, it only applies to the image after you rebuild it. When pushing the image, you will see it pushes a new digest only if the image has changed - so that's a good indicator.

Comment: Regarding what is loaded into the container - as a rule of thumb, containers should be treated as ephemeral and not contain state. If you do intend to store state in your containers, use a mounted volume to persist changes to the state between different containers, or store the state in a separate persistence layer.